# Programmatically executing the application out of sandbox in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

How to build an application which is capable of executing outside the sandbox in non-jail broken devices? Because I need to access the files and other informations like sms, call history etc ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you will probably not be able to do this. The provided SDK, and terms of using the SDK do not allow you to operate outside of the sandbox.

Even if you were able to access the information, then the app would only ever be for your own use (unless you are an enterprise developer) as it would most likely get a rejection from the App Store approvals process.

Answer (score 1):

The only access outside the sandbox that is allowed is mediated through Apple's SDK. You will only be able to access specific items, such as the Address Book or Photo library, through the iPhone OS framework.

If you have a more specific question about what you want to accomplish, perhaps we can answer based on what is currently allowed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no method that I know of to perform access outside the sandbox that is defined by the iPhone SDK.

Even if there were, your app would not be available for non-jailbroken phones, as it wouldn't be approved by the app store.